# What datatype to declare for pdf/image in java

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design

I was trying to create a domain object which have fields like Resume/ProfilePicture etc. How do i declare variable for those in my domain object? **I'm not asking how to store them**.

Basically, **what would be the equivalent of "private final String name" for resume** or things which basically contain some file. I can think of declaring them as String and then supply the path to the file. But Is there any other way for this?

Comment: Why not simply use `File`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on several factors. Here are some questions that we need to ask:

- What kind of application you are building. Desktop, Web, etc.?
- How much data do you expect to have, 10 000, 1 000 000?
- How much data will you load at the same time?

One thing you can do is use a `File` type and load the whole file. This will obviously lead to huge memory consumption, so it's not practical if you will manage a lot of data. If you don't then it's fine. You can use lazy-loading as an optimization technique to load the file only when it's needed. This will also lead to huge memory consumption if a-lot of files get loaded.

Another option is to use a `String` or a special `FilePath` (as you mentioned) value object that represents the path to the file for the profile picture or pdf resume and load the file on-demand when it's needed for display.

If you are building a WebApp and the files are stored on some network location you can use variables that represent a link to the file that can be viewed or downloaded when the user clicks on the link. You can use `String` or a special `URI` or `URL` value object.